# Collection of short stories about furry desert aliens who could switch their gender

Tags: story-identification

Was on Amazon Kindle a long time ago and found a collection of short stories about a desert planet of primitive aliens that had fur and changed gender a few times during their lives. In the story intersexual relationships were bad and the main character was born male, then changed to neuter, then to female.

Comment: Pick up a copy of *Medea: Harlan's World*.  It's not the collection you're looking for but it has a number of similar elements.  Some of the finest sf authors contributed material to the collection.

Answer (score 5):

I found it, it's the stories about the Jokka people, by M.A.C. Hogarth.

The main character I was thinking of is the protagonist of the first book, ''[The Worth of a Shell](http://www.barnesandnoble.com/w/worth-of-a-shell-mca-hogarth/1102346209?ean=9781449531652)''.